# In my compiled Livecode desktop app, the PC version saves files and folders as expected. The Mac compiled version is all wrong

Tags: macos, file, directory, livecode

In my desktop app, I have a very defined file and folder structure:

`main_folder ---folder2 ------file1 ------file2 ---folder3 ------file1 ------file2 etc...`

On PC, this writes fine.  I define the main folder and sub folders:

`put "c:\folder1\folder2\file1" into someVariable`

On Mac, I have:

`put specialfolderpath("Documents") & "/folder1/folder2/file1" into someVariable`

On PC, it writes the files to the folders as expected.  On the Mac, it seems to write a folder/file combo:

`/folder1/folder2/file1`

as a file.

For the software to work, I copy the folder/file structure to the Mac as it is on the PC.

The Mac app is not finding the existing files and is then writing new files underneath the existing folders/files as new files.

It's all very confusing and I just don't understand why it's not working as it should.

Comment: How are you using your variable later on? For me this works:
put specialfolderpath("Documents") & "/folder1/folder2/file1" into someVariable
put "Hello" into url("file:/" & someVariable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LiveCode will create a new file if it cannot find an existing one.

I don't think you can concatenate folders when using "specialFolderPath". Check out the dictionary, which only gives examples where a single folder is included.

Try this:

```
answer folder "Select Folder"
put it into folderPath
```

Check out what comes back in the local variable "it". Then test that.

Comment: Thank you.  That allowed me to see the path info and from there I was able to get it right.  Most importantly, I moved the project to my Mac and edited in Livecode from there.  It took a few attempts but in the end, I was able to store the files in the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question exactly what you are trying to do and how you are writing files to your folder structure. If I were writing a file to your apps folder structure I would do it like this (assuming main_folder is where your standalone application resides):

```
put "some text" into tTextString
put specialFolderPath("resources") & "/folder1/folder2/myfile.txt" into tPath
put textEncode(tTextString,"utf8") into URL ("binfile:" & tPath)
# textEncode is needed if you want to preserve unicode characters
# in your file, and is more reliable for cross-platform file exchange
```

SpecialFolderPath("resources") means the folder where your stack is saved in the development environment; in standalone environment, it is the folder where your standalone stack is located. Note that on a Mac this is inside the application bundle.

BTW this script should work for both Mac and Windows, *assuming that you have write permissions to that folder*. This is *not* a given for a compiled application, so instead of specialFolderPath("resources") you may want to use specialFolderPath("support") or specialFolderPath("documents"). SpecialFolderPath("resources") is a great place to store static assets your application needs, but is usually not appropriate for files written from your application.